# trouble with passing information from a form to another

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a little problem here when I'm trying to pass a cell information from a `GridView` in `Form2` back to the `Form1`.

The problem is, Form 1 is already open and I cant access because his protection level

Here goes my code.

```
private void tableDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
    Database1DataSet.TableRow SelectedRow;

    SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)tableBindingSource.Current;
    SelectedRow = (Database1DataSet.TableRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

    Form1.nome_clienteTextBox = SelectedRow.nome_cliente;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the forms designer, mark the `Modifiers` property of your textbox as `Public`

Or, better yet, have a public property on your `Form1`'s class that changes the textbox:

```
public string NomeCliente 
{
  get { return nome_clienteTextBox.Text; }
  set { nome_clienteTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

And call it like:

```
Form1.NomeCliente = SelectedRow.nome_cliente;
```

That's assuming `Form1` is your variable name (the instance of the original Form). If `Form1` is the class name, then you need to instantiate it (which you already did when you opened it) and have a reference to it somewhere on the form from where you want to change it. A possible way to do it would be:

In Form2:

```
private Form1 _myFirstForm;

public Form2(Form1 myForm)
{
  _myFirstForm = myForm;
}

private void tableDataGridView_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
  System.Data.DataRowView SelectedRowView;
  Database1DataSet.TableRow SelectedRow;

  SelectedRowView = (System.Data.DataRowView)tableBindingSource.Current;
  SelectedRow = (Database1DataSet.TableRow)SelectedRowView.Row;

  _myFirstForm.NomeCliente = SelectedRow.nome_cliente;
}
```

In Form1 (in case you open a new `Form2` from `Form1`):

```
public void OpenForm2()
{
  // this will more likely leak memory if you don't handle the 
  // disposing of Form2 somewhere else, but that's beyond the 
  // scope of this answer 
  var myForm2 = new Form2(this);  
  myForm2.Show();
}
```

Comment: You cannot access the property like that even it is public. Only when it is static. You need to use the instance of Form1.

Comment: I assumed `Form1` was the name of the variable, not the class. Will edit to specify it.

Comment: @Jcl

A weird error is prompting me when I click in the cell

Here it is:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SistemaPPE.exe

Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto. (Object reference not defined for a object instance - my translation)"

Can you still help me with these?

p.s.: I'm sorry for the bad english and the poor formating in my posts. rs

Comment: That means the instance of the object you are accessing is null (it hasn't been set a value). If the line giving that error is the `_myFirstForm.NomeCliente = SelectedRow.nome_cliente;` then probably `_myFirstForm` is `null` which means you haven't set a value for it on the constructor.